# Merge 2 unequal dataframes by ID numbers and also match rows by date

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two unequal dataframes with different patient information

DfA has details on X-rays patients have had after a procedure. The table has their ID, date of their X-ray and 15 other values as columns.

DfA

| PatientID | X-rayDate | X-ray_value1 | X-ray_value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 01/01/2017 | 1.5 | 2.5 |
| 123456 | 03/01/2018 | 2.0 | 4.2 |
| 654321 | 02/03/2017 | 4.4 | 1.1 |
| 654321 | 18/03/2018 | 7.2 | 1.2 |
| 112233 | 05/04/2017 | 0.4 | 7.6 |
| 112233 | 20/03/2018 | 4.2 | 5.5 |

DfB has the date of their procedure date and test results at 3 different time points: pre-procedure, early post procedure and 1-year post procedure going by rows. One or more of the time points may also have missing data (NA). There are 36 extra columns with more test results and their associated dates, which aren't always the same dates as others (Test1 may be on 24/01/2017 but Test15 might have been done on the 01/02/2017).

DfB

| PatientID | ProcDate | Test1 | Test1Date | Test2 | Test2Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 25/12/2016 | 400 | 25/12/2016 | NA | NA |
| 123456 | 25/12/2016 | 55 | 24/01/2017 | 22 | 26/01/2017 |
| 123456 | 25/12/2016 | 20 | 10/01/2018 | 14 | 12/01/2018 |

I need to merge the 2 dataframes together into a single dataframe that looks something like this below

Dfc

| PatientID | ProcDate | Test1 | Test1Date | Test2 | Test2Date | X-rayDate | X-ray_value1 | X-ray_value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 25/12/2016 | 400 | 25/12/2016 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 123456 | 25/12/2016 | 55 | 24/01/2017 | 22 | 26/01/2017 | 01/01/2017 | 1.5 | 2.5 |
| 123456 | 25/12/2016 | 20 | 10/01/2018 | 14 | 12/01/2018 | 03/01/2018 | 2.0 | 4.2 |

DfA is larger than DfB as it is table of values of all patients who have had a X-rays. DfB is specific for patients who have had the procedure and any patients who haven't had the procedure can be ignored for DfC. The first row for each patient should have any X-ray columns filled with NA as there is no X-ray data for the pre-procedure time point and the 2 x-ray measurements should match to the closest dates early post-procedure and 1-year post-procedure.

So far I have tried to merge using:

```
library(dyplr)
DfC<-left_join(DFB, DfA, by="Patient ID")
```

This duplicates values of the DfB for each row and some Patient ID's lose an entire row of data for time point and I can't figure out why. (I apologise for not sharing data for a reproducible example as it is actual patient data and I can't-HIPAA and all). I've tried to filter the duplicated data row by row into a new DfCv2 but I can't figure it out.

How do I merge the two dataframes together to get DfC?

Comment: the question is why
to `test1 == 55` do you want assign X-rays of `01/01/2017`,
to `test1 == 20` assign X-rays of `03/01/2018`,
and to `test1 == 400` assign `NA`? how to identify it?

Comment: `left_join(left_df, right_df)` will remove all rows of `right_df` which do not match to `left_df`. That is the nature of left join. `full_join` will keep all rows instead and fills missing columns with NA. Row duplication is also a feature of joining tables. Use `distinct` to remove them afterwards.